# Querying UNIX date stamp for YEAR

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord, where-clause

I have a UNIX timestamp like `1474557480`.

I need to query `WHERE` the year of this stamp is `20XX`.

I have tried:

```
ee()->db->where('YEAR(cd.field_id_36)', $tour_year, FALSE);
```

Can anyone direct me how this should be done?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to first find out the year from your timestamp as below :-

```
$yr =  date('Y', '1474557480');
```

Now you can use this variable inside the where condition :-

```
$this->db->where('cd.field_id_36', $yr);
```

Comment: Thank you. I realised that I am actually trying to select just the year from the column, not the answer. See my modified question code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

```
ee()->db->where('YEAR(from_unixtime(cd.field_id_36))', $tour_year, FALSE);
```